# Setting up Nuxt project with Axios module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I don't seem to be getting any data out of my Axios async calls. I've set up my calls in my Nuxt config like so:

```js
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/axios',
],
```

and in my component like so:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        {{audioUrls}}
        {{ip}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Audio",
    data() {
        return {
            audioUrls: null,
        }
    },
    async asyncData({ $axios }) {
        const ip = await $axios.get('http://icanhazip.com')
        return { ip }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.audioUrls = this.asyncData()
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm not getting any errors or data coming through to my app.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you await for your function ?

Comment: For which function?

Comment: What exactly you're doing with the value you got? Any template to show?

Comment: ```<template>
    <div>
        {{audioUrls}}
        {{ip}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "Audio",
    data() {
        return {
            audioUrls: null,
        }
    },
    async asyncData({ $axios }) {
        const ip = await this.$axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com')
        return { ip }
    },
    mounted() {
        const ip = this.$axios.$get('http://icanhazip.com')
        this.audioUrls = ip
    }
}```

Comment: @raina77ow it's a very simple component so far, just trying to get data to show up

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrectly using the return value of `$axios.get()` (i.e., a [`Response`](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) object):

```js
// ❌ DON'T DO THIS: $axios.get() returns a Response,
// whose data prop contains actual response data
const ip = await $axios.get(...)
return { ip }

// ✅ OK
const { data: ip } = await $axios.get(...)
return { ip }
```

And it looks like you're trying to use `asyncData()` in a component, but [components don't have `asyncData()`](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/async-data-components/). You could either move `asyncData()` into a page (e.g., `pages/index.vue`); or use [`fetch()`](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/components-glossary/pages-fetch) instead, which also works in a component. Don't forget to declare `ip` in `data()`:

```js
// MyComponent.vue
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      ip: '',
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    const { data } = await this.$axios.get('http://icanhazip.com')
    this.ip = data
  }
}
```